# Simple date format. Date parsing

Tags: android, date, parsing, simpledateformat

I try to parse date like: Tue, 08 Sep 2015 12:32:55 +0300 and appy next pattern:`SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss zzzz");`
But I catch exception java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sun, 13 Sep 2015 17:25:26 +0300" (at offset 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the code to

```
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzzz", Locale.US);
```

**Edit:**

Additional amendment I have changed `hh` in your code to `HH` for 24 hours format